# Display uploaded file django

Tags: python, django

### How can I retrieve and display a uploaded file?

This is my model to upload a file

### /models.py/

```
class resmodel(models.Model):
   file_header = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   upload_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

### /resume.html/

```
<form action="." method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>File Header</label>
        </td>
        <td>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label>{% for detail in profile_detail %}{{ detail.file_header }}{% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>FILE</label>
        </td>
        <td>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label> {{ MEDIA_URL }}{% for detail in profile_detail %}{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{detail.upload_file}}{% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

### /urls.py/

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^profile/$', resview),)
```

### /settings.py/ In settings my media path and url is..

```
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/var/www/project/media/'
```

### Ho can i display the uploaded file in my html page..

### Suggest me, thanks.

Comment: is the file of a specific format (image, pdf, .doc, ...)?

Comment: Assuming you mean an MS Office `.doc`, I don't think most browsers (by default) include support for displaying those. You'd have to convert it to HTML first. Google for `convert doc to html`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the URL of the uploaded file by accessing the `url` property. See: [`FieldField.url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) in the Django Documentation.

In your case you would do something like: `<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{detail.upload_file.url}}">Uploaded File</a>`, which would create a hyperlink to the file, allowing it to be downloaded by clicking the link from the resume.html template.

Comment: Tats fine, but actually i want to display the contents of an uploded file. What could work for this?